# How to insert multiple rows into database by checked box?

Tags: php, html

I have a table generated dynamically from a database named 'submittbl'. Each row has a checkbox generated with it dynamically.

I want to be able to insert rows checked into database named 'marktbl'. What I have tried so far only gets the first row saved to database instead of the row I check/select. But if I check all rows, all the rows gets saved properly. How can I insert the checked rows?

I have tried many solutions haven't worked.

```
//to get records from database dynamically

<?php
            if(isset($_POST['find_btn']))
            {
                if(empty($_POST['s_lev']) && empty($_POST['s_sem']))
                {
                    $msgerr = "<b>Notice: </b>" . "No categories selected.";
                }
                else
                {
                    $selev=$_POST['s_lev'];
                    $sesem=$_POST['s_sem'];
                    $sql = "SELECT *FROM submittbl WHERE CourseCode = ? AND Level = ? AND Semester = ?";
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bind_param("sss",$pcode, $plevel, $psems);
                    $pcode = $_SESSION['ccode'];
                    $plevel = $selev;
                    $psems = $sesem;
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result = $stmt->get_result();
                    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
                    if($num_rows>0)
                    {
                        while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                            $sn = $rows['SN'];
                            $name = $rows['StudentName'];
                            $regno = $rows['RegNo'];
                            $asmid = $rows['AssignmentID'];
                            $code = $rows['CourseCode'];
                            $lev = $rows['Level'];
                            $sem = $rows['Semester'];
                            $det = $rows['SubmissionDate'];
                            $doc = $rows['Document'];
                            $score = $rows['Score'];
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                            <td><input type='checkbox' name='delChk[]' value='<?php echo $sn; ?>'><?php echo $sn; ?></input></td>
                            <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $regno; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $asmid; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $det; ?></td>
                            <input type='hidden' name='sn' value='<?php echo $sn; ?>'></input>
                            <input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='<?php echo $name; ?>'></input>
                            <input type='hidden' name='regno[]' value='<?php echo $regno; ?>'></input>
                            <input type='hidden' name='asmid[]' value='<?php echo $asmid; ?>'></input>
                            <input type='hidden' name='ccode[]' value='<?php echo $code; ?>'></input>
                            <input type='hidden' name='level[]' value='<?php echo $lev; ?>'></input>
                            <input type='hidden' name='semester[]' value='<?php echo $sem; ?>'></input>
                            <input type='hidden' name='det[]' value='<?php echo $sub; ?>'></input>
                            <input type='hidden' name='doc[]' value='<?php echo $doc; ?>'></input>
                            <input type='hidden' name='score[]' value='<?php echo $score; ?>'></input>
                            <td><?php echo "<a href='download_submitted.php?id=$asmid'><img src=img/downloads.png width=10% height=10% alt='download'>Download</a>"; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $msgerr = "<b>Notice: </b>" . "Oops! No records found for the selected categories.";
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>

                //to insert into markedtbl database
               //this is where I'm having the whole problem

                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['upload']))
                    {
                        if(!isset($_POST['delChk']))
                        {
                            $msgerr = "<b>Notice: </b>" . "No records selected - select/mark records to upload.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                //-------------------get all IDs in checkbox by loop------------------
                           
                            $checked = $_POST['delChk'];

                            foreach($checked as $k=>$v)
                            {
                                if($checked[$k] == TRUE)
                                {
                                $chkrow = $checked[$k];
                                $name = $_POST['name'];
                                $regno = $_POST['regno'];
                                $asmid = $_POST['asmid'];
                                $code = $_POST['ccode'];
                                $level = $_POST['level'];
                                $sems = $_POST['semester'];
                                $det = $_POST['det'];
                                $doc = $_POST['doc'];
                                $score = $_POST['score'];
                               
                //-------------prepare sql query to update score in database------------------------
                            $sql = "INSERT INTO marktbl(NSN, StudentName, RegNo, AssignmentID, CourseCode, Level, Semester, DateSubmitted, Document, Score)
                                    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                                $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $pcount, $pname, $pregno, $pasmid, $pcode, $plevel, $psems, $pdet, $pdoc, $pscore);
                                $pcount = $chkrow;
                                $pname = $name[$k];
                                $pregno = $regno[$k];
                                $pasmid = $asmid[$k];
                                $pcode = $code[$k];
                                $plevel = $level[$k];
                                $psems = $sems[$k];
                                $pdet = $det[$k];
                                $pdoc = $doc[$k];
                                $pscore = $score[$k];
                                $stmt->execute();
                            }
                                }
                                if($conn->error)
                                {
                                    $msgerr = $conn->error;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "<script> alert('Assignment uploaded for marking.')</script>";
                                }
                        }
                            //}
                    }
                ?>
<?php echo "<span class='err'>" . $msgerr . "</span>"; ?><br>

                <td class='td'>
                <button class='upload' name='upload' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to upload selected assignments for marking?')"
                >Upload for Marking</button>
                </td>
</form>
```

Comment: so let's say you have 4 array keys and if key 0 and key 2 are selected insert them into table marktbl, right?

Comment: add please your data print_r($_POST) - very hard to imagine data structure.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to stackoverflow! It's best to format your code a bit so that it only contains the relevant bits in different code boxes and that there is very little "extra" text - this helps us understand and answer your question. I'll edit the question a bit :)

Comment: @PlamenPenchev, exactly. But what I get is only first key inserted no matter what key I select

Comment: I was about to edit your code, but it was a bit difficult to parse. I highly suggest that the 1st thing you do is improve the code styling and indentation you use, this helps you spot issues and makes it easier for us to understand your code. If you have multiple files here, please add the code so that it's one file per code box. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so I will try to write you a sample of your idea, hope will works.
so you have array of users for my example with four keys

```
$users = [
 0 => [
    'selected' => true,
    'name' => 'Name 1',

  ],
1 => [
    'selected' => false,
    'name' => 'Name 2',

  ],
2 => [
    'selected' => true,
    'name' => 'Name 3',

  ],
3 => [
    'selected' => false,
    'name' => 'Name 4',

  ],
];

foreach ($users as $user) {
    if (!$user['selected]) {
       continue;
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO marktbl(
        NSN,
        StudentName,
        RegNo,
        AssignmentID,
        CourseCode,
        Level,
        Semester,
        DateSubmitted,
        Document,
         Score
      ) VALUES(
       :name,
       :lastname,...
      )";
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $params = [
         ':name' => $user['name'],
         ':lastname' => $user['lastname'],...
      ];
      try {
         $stmt->execute($params); 
      } catch(Exception $e) {
         echo $e->getMessage();
      }
      

}
```

I think your code should look like this. You can easy set a flag for every selected element and then filter data by this flag.

Comment: how do I implement that with checkboxes which are generated dynamically?